# Dart DateTime.toIso8601String() throwing exception when inserting into SQFlite database

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

I am having trouble inserting a `DateTime.toIso8601String()` into a SQLite (SQFlite) database in Dart. The issue I am having is with a `property_model` class, who's only job is to interact with the database and hold data. I have an almost identical `address_model` class that works how I expect it, but I am having trouble with the `property_model`. Whenever I try to call the `Property.insert()` method, I get this error:

> E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'DateTime'

I don't have this issue with the very similar Address class though, and I am pretty stumped. Here are the property_model, address_model, and database files I am using (the database.dart file is a singleton that I use throughout the application).

**property_model.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'package:villadex/model/database.dart' as db;
import 'package:villadex/model/address_model.dart';

class Property {
  /// Constructors
  Property({
    required this.name,
    required Address address,
    required this.owner,
  })  : _address = address,
        _primaryKey = null,
        _dateCreated = DateTime.now();

  Property.existing(
      {required this.name,
      required Address address,
      required this.owner,
      required int? primaryKey,
      required DateTime dateCreated})
      : _address = address,
        _primaryKey = primaryKey,
        _dateCreated = dateCreated;

  Property.fromJSON({required Map<String, dynamic> json})
      : name = json['name'],
        owner = json['owner'],
        _address = Address.fromJson(json: json['location']),
        _primaryKey = json['property_id'],
        _dateCreated = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(json['dateCreated']);

  /// Data
  String name;
  String? owner;
  final Address _address;

  /*final List<Event> calendar;
  final List<Expenditure> expenditures;
  final List<Associate> associates;
  final List<Earning> earnings;*/

  final int? _primaryKey;
  final DateTime _dateCreated;

  ///Methods
  Future<void> insert() async {
    String dateCreated = _dateCreated.toIso8601String().trim();

    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      // SQFlite sets the primary key
      'name': name,
      'owner': owner,
      'location': address.toJson(),
      'dateCreated': dateCreated,
    };

    await db.DatabaseConnection.database.then((databaseConnection) => {
          databaseConnection?.insert('properties', data,
              conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace)
        });
  }

  static Future<Property?> fetchById(int id) async {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE property_id = $id";

    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>? rawData;
    await db.DatabaseConnection.database.then(
        (databaseConnection) => {rawData = databaseConnection?.rawQuery(sql)});

    return rawData?.then((data) {
      return Property.fromJSON(json: data[0]);
    });
  }

  /// Getters
  Address get address => _address;
}
```

**address_model.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:villadex/model/database.dart' as db;

class Address {
  /// Constructors
  Address(
      {required this.street1,
      this.street2 = '',
      required this.city,
      this.state = '',
      this.zip = '',
      required this.country})
      : _dateCreated = DateTime.now(),
        _primaryKey = null,
        _propertyId = null,
        _associateId = null;

  Address.existing({
    required this.street1,
    this.street2 = '',
    required this.city,
    this.state = '',
    this.zip = '',
    required this.country,
    required DateTime dateCreated,
    required int primaryKey,
    int? propertyKey,
    int? associateKey,
  })  : _dateCreated = dateCreated,
        _primaryKey = primaryKey,
        _propertyId = propertyKey,
        _associateId = associateKey;

  Address.fromJson({required Map<String, dynamic> json})
      : street1 = json['street1'],
        street2 = json['street2'],
        city = json['city'],
        state = json['state'],
        zip = json['zip'],
        country = json['country'],
        _primaryKey = json['address_id'],
        _propertyId = json['property_id'],
        _associateId = json['associate_id'],
        _dateCreated = DateTime.parse(json['_dateCreated']);

  /// Data
  final String street1;
  final String street2;
  final String city;
  final String state;
  final String zip;
  final String country;

  final int? _primaryKey;
  final int? _propertyId;
  final int? _associateId;
  final DateTime _dateCreated;

  /// Methods
  Future<void> insert() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      // SQFlite sets the primaryKey
      'property_id': _propertyId,
      'associate_id': _associateId,
      'dateCreated': _dateCreated.toIso8601String().trim(),
      'street1': street1,
      'street2': street2,
      'city': city,
      'zip': zip,
      'country': country
    };

    await db.DatabaseConnection.database.then((databaseConnection) =>
        {databaseConnection?.insert('addresses', data)});
  }

  // Returns an address by ID
  static Future<Address?> fetchById(int id) async {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE address_id = $id";

    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>? rawData;
    await db.DatabaseConnection.database.then(
        (databaseConnection) => {rawData = databaseConnection?.rawQuery(sql)});

    return rawData?.then((data) {
      return Address.fromJson(json: data[0]);
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'street1': street1,
      'street2': street2,
      'city': city,
      'state': state,
      'zip': zip,
      'country': country,
      'address_id': _primaryKey,
      'property_id': _propertyId,
      'associate_id': _associateId,
      'dateCreated': _dateCreated
    };
  }

  /// Getters
  String get fullAddress =>
      street1 +
      " " +
      street2 +
      ", " +
      city +
      " " +
      state +
      " " +
      zip +
      ", " +
      country;

  DateTime get dateCreated => _dateCreated;

  int get key => _primaryKey ?? 0;

  /// Setters
}
```

**database.dart**

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:villadex/model/property_model.dart';


class DatabaseConnection {
  //static final DatabaseConnection instance = DatabaseConnection.init();

  //DatabaseConnection._init();

  /// Database variable
  static Database? _database;

  /// Getter for the database
  static Future<Database?> get database async {
    // If _database is null, set it equal to the return value of _initDB
    _database ??= await _initDB('database3');

    return _database;
  }

  /// Initialize database
  static Future<Database?> _initDB(String dbname) async {
    final dbPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(dbPath.toString(), dbname);

    var dbInstance = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDatabase);

    return dbInstance;
  }

  /// Create the database
  static Future _createDatabase(Database database, int version) async {
    Batch batch = database.batch();

    /// CREATE PROPERTIES TABLE
    batch.execute('''CREATE TABLE properties(
      property_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      dateCreated TEXT NOT NULL,

      name TEXT NOT NULL,
      location TEXT NOT NULL,
      owner TEXT NOT NULL,
    
      calendar TEXT,
      expenditures TEXT,
      associates TEXT,
      earnings TEXT
      );''');

    /// CREATE EXPENDITURES TABLE
    batch.execute('''CREATE TABLE expenditures(
      expenditure_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      property_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      dateCreated TEXT NOT NULL,

      name TEXT NOT NULL,
      amount REAL NOT NULL,
      numberUnits INTEGER NOT NULL,
      isPaid INTEGER NOT NULL,

      description TEXT,
      category TEXT,
      date TEXT,
      associates TEXT,

      FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
        REFERENCES properties(property_id)
      );''');

    /// CREATE EARNINGS TABLE
    batch.execute(''' CREATE TABLE earnings(
      earning_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      property_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      dateCreated TEXT NOT NULL,

      name TEXT NOT NULL,
      amount REAL NOT NULL,

      description TEXT,
      category TEXT,
      date TEXT,
      associates TEXT,

      FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
        REFERENCES properties(property_id)
      );''');

    /// CREATE CATEGORIES TABLE
    batch.execute(''' CREATE TABLE categories(
      category_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      dateCreated TEXT NOT NULL,

      name TEXT NOT NULL
      );''');

    /// CREATE ASSOCIATES TABLE
    batch.execute(''' CREATE TABLE associates(
      associate_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      property_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      dateCreated TEXT NOT NULL,

      name TEXT NOT NULL,

      contact TEXT,
      role TEXT,
      payments TEXT,
      FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
        REFERENCES properties (property_id)
      );''');

    /// CREATE CONTACTS TABLE
    batch.execute(''' CREATE TABLE contact (
      associate_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

      phoneNumber TEXT,
      email TEXT,
      FOREIGN KEY (associate_id)
        REFERENCES associates (associate_id)
      );''');

    /// CREATE ADDRESSES TABLE
    batch.execute(''' CREATE TABLE addresses (
      address_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      property_id INTEGER,
      associate_id INTEGER,
      dateCreated TEXT NOT NULL,

      street1 TEXT NOT NULL,
      street2 TEXT,
      city TEXT NOT NULL,
      zip TEXT,
      state TEXT,
      country TEXT,
      FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
        REFERENCES properties (property_id),
      FOREIGN KEY (associate_id)
        REFERENCES associates (associate_id)
      );''');

    /// CREATE EVENT TABLE
    batch.execute(''' CREATE TABLE event (
      event_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      property_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      dateCreated TEXT NOT NULL,

      name TEXT NOT NULL,

      description TEXT,
      address TEXT,
      associates TEXT,
      expenditures TEXT,
      earnings TEXT,

      FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
        REFERENCES properties (property_id)
      );''');

    batch.commit();
  }

  Future close() async {
    _database?.close;
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but all the places where you do `await db.DatabaseConnection.database.then((databaseConnection) => { ... });` are wrong.  `(databaseConnection) => { ... }` creates an anonymous function that returns a `Set` literal.  You intend want just `(databaseConnection) => ...`.  Furthermore, it's bad style to mix `await` and `Future.then`.  Just use `await`: `var databaseConnection = await db.DatabaseConnection.database; ...`.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. The address object within my property object did not turn its DateTime object into a string during the address.toJson() method, which is why it was giving me that error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).